# can ADFS idP send "user not found" to SP?

Tags: adfs3.0

My customers land on my ADFS IDP-initiated login page. They get authenticated and redirected to SP. Everything looks nice. But I have a few extra users that are not part of idP database (AD domain). I would like to authenticate them locally in my SP but they are never redirected there. They get stuck in ADFS with "wrong username/password".

Is it possible to send SAML message with some "user not found" message to SP ? 
I'm using ADFS 3.0

Thank you very much for all ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - that's not the way most IDP work.

You can't leave the login page until you are authenticated.

What you can do is add another IDP for your other users e.g. [Identity Server 3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) and then federate it with ADFS.